# Redirecting subdomain to a url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have a subdomain lets say http://coding.designzzz.com/ i want to redirect it to http://www.designzzz.com/tag/coding/

What i am looking forward to is whatever the further url in the subdomain i want it to land on www.designzzz.com/tag/coding/

A few redirects i tried were having this behavior.. if coding.designzzz.com/abc.html is run they were redirecting it to www.designzzz.com/tag/coding/abc.html.. i just want the urls to redirect to www.designzzz.com/tag/coding/ and not the preceding urls/page.
And yes 301 redirects.

Help is appreciated.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^coding\.designzzz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.designzzz.com/tag/coding/? [L,R=301]
```